# MFC: CMFCMenuBar.SetMenuFont() not changing the font?

Tags: winapi, mfc, menubar, cmfctoolbar

Changed an MFC app to per-monitor DPI aware.  On the `WM_DPICHANGED` message I wanted to changed the fonts of the CMFCMenuBar to be scaled correctly.  So I added:

```
  LOGFONT logfont;
  GetGlobalData()->fontRegular.GetLogFont(&logfont);
  logfont.lfHeight=g_DPIHelper.ScaleNonClientMetricsFont(logfont.lfHeight);
  if (!m_wndMenuBar.SetMenuFont(&logfont)) {
    TRACE0("Unable to set menu font\n");
  }
```

I confirmed that logfont.lfHeight went from -11 to -17 in the test case.  I confirmed the `SetMenuFont()` call returned success.   Yet the `CMFCMenuBar` font shown on the menu bar is the same size as it was before.  What am I missing?

TIA!!

Comment: Hi, if you have solve the issue by yourself, you could [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after `WM_DPICHANGED` a `WM_SETTINGCHANGED` is sent and MFC then calls `AFX_GLOBAL_DATA::OnSettingsChange()` which calls `UpdateFonts()` which uses `GetNonClientMetrics()` which resets it back to the wrong size because the size is based on when the application started.

On `WM_DPICHANGED` calculate your scaling factor.  Then do the actual font change in `WM_SETTINGCHANGED` which allows the font change size to take affect when you change the DPI of the screen (not sure if `WM_SETTINGCHANGED` called if moved to another window, if not the change can be done in `WM_DPICHANGED`.  Here's one method:

```
void CMainFrame::OnSettingChange(UINT uFlags, LPCTSTR lpszSection)
{
  CFrameWndEx::OnSettingChange(uFlags, lpszSection);

  LOGFONT logfont;
  GetGlobalData()->fontRegular.GetLogFont(&logfont);
  logfont.lfHeight=g_DPIHelper.Scale(-11);
  if (!m_wndMenuBar.SetMenuFont(&logfont)) {
    TRACE0("Unable to set menu fonts\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: A DC can span multiple monitors, so it doesn't make sense to talk of the DPI of a DC unless there's a rule that says it will be consistent.